# I am trying to make a loop that will check if input is a number and if not ask again

Tags: c++, loops, error-handling

So here is the code I have so far. I tried a few things like isDigit(nPlay) and !cin. Maybe I need a different loop. When I do either one, if I input a number more than 4 it acts like it is supposed too. But when I put in a letter or word then it goes into a infinite loop.

```
int view::numPlayer() {
int nPlay = 0;
while( nPlay == 0 ) {
    cout << "How many players will there be?" << endl;
    cin >> nPlay;
    if(nPlay > 4 || nPlay < 2 || !cin) {
        nPlay = 0;
    }
    system("CLS");
}
return nPlay;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `failbit` flag on `std::cin`, when set, isn't automatically cleared. That means the `!cin` will always be true. You have to clear the flag manually with the [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) function.

Comment: The link you provided for 'clear()' also has a good example for the OP to follow for reading a number. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to read an integer, then clear the stream's failbit if that failed, I'd read a string, and repeat if the conversion didn't succeed.

```
int value;
char *pos;
std::string temp;

cout << "How many players will there be?";
do {
    std::getline(cin, temp);
    nPlay = strtol(temp.c_str(), &pos, 10);
} while (*pos != '\0');
```